# ServiceBus Trigger is not firing

Tags: .net-core, azure-function-app

ServiceBus Trigger is not firing when it has been idle for a long time. I am sending all the messages to the azure queue once in a day. Then my service bus trigger will read messages from the queue, after a few days, I observed the service bus trigger was not reading

Currently, I am using the App service plan. I am not sure why it not triggering.

Please help me how to resolve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: make sure your app service plan is configured to always on mode

Comment: Can you share your code?